# Animate many Usercontrols as endless list

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

i get a variable number of user controls ordered as a list. My goal is to scroll these controls upwards. When the topmost control left the visible area i want to remove it from the top and append to the end.

First i tried to animate every control via ThicknessAnimation, but i think this is inefficient as there could be 50+ controls.

As a visual help so see what i include a [picture](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/7299/pngpq.png) of what i try to achieve.

Any ideas how to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [LoopPanel Sample Application](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/panels/) from Dr. WPF you may interested in.